# Excel VBA ComboBox RowSource Issue - Keep getting wrong data source

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Very strange! I've wasted more than 2 hours trying to figure out what went wrong. It seems that despite specifying the RowSource of the combobox (in red rectangular), data is sourced from the ListBox instead. "wsSubject" is the worksheet I'd like to populate my ComboBox with. I should note if I change the RowSource column, I get the data from corresponding column data from the ListBox.

Version: Excel 2010.

[image: Here is the userform that I have]

And the code behind it:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
If MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then
     'set data source for Student Search Criteria

   cmbSubject.RowSource = wsSubject.Range("B2:B12").Address
    lbxStu.RowSource = wsStudent_Search.Range("A1:F100").Address
    lbxStu.ColumnCount = 5
    lbxStu.BoundColumn = 1
End If
```

Comment: You need to include the sheet name in the rowsource, not just the range address

Comment: As per Tim's suggestion, you would change `.Address` to `.Address(,,,true)`.

Comment: @Domenic - maybe i upvoted that comment too soon. The 4th parameter for `Address` is "A1" which defaults to true anyways.  ([Reference](https://support.office.com/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)) ...so isn't your suggestion the same as `Address` by itself?  Isn't the correct solution to simply *remove* `.Address` from both lines?

Comment: @ashleedawg Actually, RowSource requires a string.  And Address by itself defaults to a local reference (ie. A1).  When the fourth parameter is set to True, it returns an external reference (ie. [Book1]Sheet1!$A$1).  I guess for clarity I should have offered .Address(External:=True) instead. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Address)

Comment: Or  use .List instead, cmbSubject.List = wsSubject.Range("B2:B12").Value

Comment: Adding the address parameters did the trick! Thanks Tim & Domenic!

Comment: @EvR I tried your solution and it works too. Many thanks!